# jQuery navigating XML parent child nodes and selecting appropriate attributes from each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am creating a templating system which can be interpreted at client side with Javascript to construct a fill in the blanks form e.g. for a letter to a customer etc.

I have the template constructed and the logic set out in pseudo code, however my unfamiliarity with jQuery I could use some direction to get me started.

The basic idea is there is a markup in my text node that denotes a field e.g. ${prologue} this is then added to an array called "fields" which will then be used to search for corresponding node names in the xml.

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>

    <text>${Prologue} - Dear ${Title} ${Surname}. This is a message from FUBAR. An engineer called but was unable to gain access, a new appointment has been made for ${ProductName} with order number ${VOLNumber}, on ${AppointmentDate} between ${AppointmentSlot}.
Please ensure you are available at your premises for the engineer. If this is not convenient, go to fubar.com or call 124125121515 before 12:00 noon the day before your appointment. Please refer to your order confirmation for details on what will happen on the day. ${Epilogue} - Free text field for advisor input<
</text>

    <inputTypes>
        <textBox type="text" fixed="n" size="100" alt="Enter a value">
            <Prologue size="200" value="BT ENG Appt Reschedule 254159" alt="Prologue field"></Prologue>
            <Surname value="Hoskins"></Surname>
            <ProductName value=""></ProductName>
            <VOLNumber size="8" value="" ></VOLNumber>
            <Epilogue value=""></Epilogue>  
        </textBox>
        <date type="datePicker" fixed="n" size="8" alt="Select a suitable appointment date">
            <AppointmentDate></AppointmentDate>
        </date>
        <select type="select" >
            <Title alt="Select the customers title">
                <values>
                    <Mr selected="true">Mr</Mr>
                    <Miss>Miss</Miss>
                    <Mrs>Mrs</Mrs>
                    <Dr>Dr</Dr>
                    <Sir>Sir</Sir>                  
                </values>
            </Title>
            <AppointmentSlot alt="Select the appointment slot">
                <values>
                    <Morning>9:30am - 12:00pm</Morning>
                    <Afternoon>1:00pm - 5:00pm</Afternoon>
                    <Evening>6:00pm - 9:00pm</Evening>
                </values>
            </AppointmentSlot>
        </select>
    </inputTypes>
</message>
```

**Pseudocode**

```
Get list of tags from text node and build array called "fields"
For each item in "fields" array:
Find node in xml that equals array item's name
Get attributes of that node
Jump to parent node
Get attributes of parent node
If attributes of parent node != child node then ignore
Else add the parent attributes to the result
Build html for field using all the data gathered from above
```

**Addendums**

Is this logic ok, is it possible to start at the parent of the node and navigate downwards instead?

Also with regards to inheritence could we get the parent attributes and if the child attributes are different then add them to the result? What about if the number of attributes in the parent does not equal the number in the child?

Please do not provide fully coded solutions, just a little teasers to get me started.

Here is what I have so far which is extracting the tags from text node

```
//get value of node "text" in xml
    var start = $(xml).find("text").text().indexOf('$');
    var end = $(xml).find("text").text().indexOf('}');
    var tag = "";
    var inputType;

    // find all tags and add them to a tag array
    while (start >= 0)
    {
        //console.log("Reach In Loop " + start)
        tag = theLetter.slice(start + 2, end);
        tagArray.push(tag);
        tagReplaceArray.push(theLetter.slice(start, end + 1));
        start = theLetter.indexOf('$', start + 1);
        end = theLetter.indexOf('}', end + 1);
    }
```

Any other recommendations or links to similar problems would be welcome.

Thankyou!

Comment: Do you control the XML generation ? Is that in some other process where you could maybe change it a bit ?

Comment: Nope assume I cannot control it

Comment: Why do you give -1 to "loosebruce"? At the time I have posted this comment it was already -4 without any explanation. Is it qood StackOverflow etiquette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get list of tags from text node and build array called "fields"

To create the array I would rather user [regular expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp), this is one of the best use for it (in my opinion) because we are indeed searching for a pattern :

```js
var reg = /\$\{(\w+)\}/gm;
var i = 0;
var fields = new Array();

while (  (m = reg.exec(txt)) !== null)
{
    fields[i++] = m[1];
}
```

### For each item in "fields" array

jQuery offers some [utility functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/) :

To iterate through your fields you could do this : `$.each(fields, function(index, value){});`

### Navigating through the nodes and retrieving the values

Just use the [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) like you are already doing.

### Building the HTML

I would create templates objects for each types you would take in charge (in this example : `Text`, `Select`)

Then using said templates you could replace the tokens with the HTML of your templates.

### Displaying the HTML

Last step would be to parse the result string and append it at the right place:

```js
var ResultForm = $.parseHTML(txt); 

$("#DisplayDiv").append(ResultForm);
```

### Conclusion

Like you asked, I did not prepare anything that works right out of the box, I hope it will help you prepare your own answer. (And then I hope you will share it with the community)

Answer (score 5):

I am using a similar technique to do html templating.

Instead of working with elements, I find it easier to work with a string and then convert it to html. In your case with jQuery, you could do something similar:

Have your xml as a string:

```
var xmlString='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><message><text>${Prologue} - Dear ${Title} ${Surname}... ';
```

Iterate through the string to do the replacements with a regex ($1 is the captured placeholder, for example Surname):

```
xmlString.replace(/$\{([^}]+)}/g,function($0,$1)...}
```

Convert to nodes if needed:

```
var xml=$(xmlString);
```

The benefits of the regex:

- faster (just a string, you're not walking the DOM)
- global replace (for example if Surname appears several times), just loop through your object properties once
- simple regex /${([^}]+)}/ to target the placeholder

Comment: @loosebruce do you find it fair to downvote an answer because of information that was missing in the question?

Comment: @Christophe its not good that loosebruce downvoted your answer, but it was an explanation given for this downvote. I think the explanation is wrong too. loosebruce has many downvotes without any explanation - thats not good I think. I gave you +1

Comment: @MikroDel I'm with you, people should explain a downvote and I don't know why stackoverflow doesn't make it mandatory. Just so you know, moderators have done some cleanup on this post, some initial comments from loosebruce might explain the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a framework to get you going, like you asked.

first concept is using a regex to just find all matches of ${ }. it returns an array like ["${one}","${t    w   0  }","${   three}"].

second concept is a htmlGenerator json object mapping "inputTypes-->childname" to a function responsible for the html print out.

third is not to forget about natural javascript. `.localname` will give you the xml element's name, and `node.attributes` [should](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_attributes.asp) give you a [namedNodeMap](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_namednodemap.asp) back (remember not to perform natural javascript against the jquery object, make sure you're referencing the node element jQuery found for you).

the actual flow is simple.

find all the '${}'tokens and store the result in an array.

find all the tokens in the xml document and using their parents info, store the html in an map of `{"${one}":"<input type='text' .../>","${two}":"<select><option value='hello'>world!</option></select>" ...}`

iterate through the map and replace every token in the source text with the html you want.

## javascript

```js
    var $xmlDoc = $(xml); //store the xml document
    var tokenSource =$xmlDoc.find("message text").text(); 
    var tokenizer=/${[^}]+/g; //used to find replacement locations
    var htmlGenerators = {
      "textBox":function(name,$elementParent){
    //default javascript .attributes returns a namedNodeMap, I think jquery can handle it, otherwise parse the .attributes return into an array or json obj first.
      var parentAttributes = ($elementParent[0] && $elementParent.attributes)?$elementParent.attributes:null;
    //this may be not enough null check work, but you get the idea
      var specificAttributes =$elementParent.find(name)[0].attributes;
      var combinedAttributes = {};
      if(parentAttributes && specificAttributes){
    //extend or overwrite the contents of the first obj with contents from 2nd, then 3rd, ... then nth [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)
          $.extend(combinedAttributes,parentAttributes,specificAttributes);
      }
      return $("<input>",combinedAttributes);
    },
      "date":function(name,$elementParent){
       //whatever you want to do for a 'date' text input
    },
      "select":function(name,$elementParent){
      //put in a default select box implementation, obviously you'll need to copy options attributes too in addition to their value / visible value.
    }
    };
    var html={};
    var tokens = tokenSource.match(tokenizer); //pull out each ${elementKey}
    for(index in tokens){
      var elementKey = tokens[index].replace("${","").replace("}"),"");//chomp${,}
      var $elementParent = $xmlDoc.find(elementKey).parent();//we need parent attributes.  javascript .localname should have the element name of your xml node, in this case "textBox","date" or "select".  might need a [0].localname....
      var elementFunction = ($elementParent.localname)?htmlGenerators[elementParent.localname]:null; //lookup the html generator function
      if(elementFunction != null){ //make sure we found one
        html[tokens[index]] = elementFunction(elementKey,elementParent);//store the result
      }
    }
  

      for(index in html){
       //for every html result, replace it's token
          tokenSource = tokenSource.replace(index,html[index]);
        }
```